# Characterization for an umbilical point .

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $x$ be a patch in a surface $M$ then A point in M is umbilic iff there exists a constant $K$ such that 
$$L_{11}=Kg_{11}$$
$$L_{12}=Kg_{12}$$
$$L_{22}=Kg_{22}$$

Where $x=x(u,v)$ and $L_{ij}=<x_{ij},n>$ and $g_{ij}=<x_i,x_j>$

The proof of ($\Rightarrow$)
$L$ is a shape operator in my notation

We have $$L(x_u)=K (x_u)$$
$$L(x_v)=K (x_v)$$
since $k_1=k_2=K$ (by Def  $P$ $\in$ M is umbilic point if $k_1=k_2$)where $k_1$,$k_2$ are the principal directions at $P$

Now $$L_{11}=<L(x_u),x_u>=<Kx_u,x_u>=Kg_{11}$$
How Can I prove the other direction ?
I want to prove that $k_1=k_2=K$

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the coefficients $L^i_{\;j}$ of the shape operator using the formula $L^i_{\;j}=L_{jk}g^{ki}$ but the simplest solution would be to choose a coordinate patch where the first fundamental form is diagonal (since the second fundamental form transforms nicely) and then the answer is immediate.